# python manage.py runserver not work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn django on my mac by following along with [Writing your first Django app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)

I run

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

and it creates the files it should. Then I try to start the server by running

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

It's OK,the message is :

> Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found Django version 1.4.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
>   Development server is running at http:// 127.0.0.1:8080/ Quit the
>   server with CONTROL-C.

But I when I visit the 127.0.0.1:8080, I get a 504 error page:

> This Page Cannot Be Displayed
>
> The system cannot communicate with the external server ( 127.0.0.1 ).
>   The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be
>   unreachable because of network problems. ......

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you accessing that page from the same machine it is running on?

Comment: You got error **504** or 404?

Comment: Is there any error in console window during your request handling?

Comment: Do you keep the server running?  If you close the terminal, the server stops.  Try `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then access it on `0.0.0.0:8000`.

Comment: @jpic, good point.  I personally pick random years and use them as my ports, to avoid conflict with other programs on my computer.  For example, I run one project on 2012, and another on 1976.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry, I can't follow you. All my operation is from the same machine.

Comment: @AlexG.P. The console is static when I request handling.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Yeah,I keep the server running.Aftet manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000,there's also a error page,but the error message is : DNS Resolution Failure.My net is using proxy,may be the proxy's problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are using a proxy (as mentioned in the comments). The reason for this error:

> This Page Cannot Be Displayed
>
> The system cannot communicate with the external server ( 127.0.0.1 ). The Internet server may be busy, may be permanently down, or may be unreachable because of network problems. ......

is that 127.0.0.1 is looked up at the proxy and on the proxy server there is nothing listening on port 8080

Comment: Thanks,is the proxy's problem.I was so happy to go on learning,yeah!

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I can't edit the company's proxy ,but i will try to use other servers,not 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.1,thank you,your apply, help me a lot.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: If it's a browser only setting you can disable it, use another browser, in some browsers you can set proxy exceptions (in that case for 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Use 'python manage.py runserver 8000' instead of 'python manage.py runserver 8080'
Worked for me.